DC Voltage Step-down at High Current
I have a petrol mower with an electric-start engine. The electric start is powered by a small battery of similar size and design as you might find on an electric drill or other power tool, charged by a mains-powered charger, also very similar to a drill battery charger:

After a few years of faithful service, the battery has done what I always knew was going to happen and will no longer hold a charge. Unfortunately, it is no longer possible to buy a replacement battery.
It occurs to me that a might be able to jerry-rig an arrangement that allows it to start by using one of the many drill batteries that I already own.
The problem is that the drill batteries are 18 V - and the mower only needs 10.8 V. I have successfully “jump started” it with a 12 V car jump-starter, so 12 V is a reasonable target to aim for I think.
There is a Youtube Video of somebody successfully modifying his mower for an 18 V battery, by using a cheap buck convertor. He seemed to get away with it, in spite of not really considering the very high current flow that is needed for this application.
My thinking is that the 2 Ah battery will turn the engine for about 1 minute with a full charge, maybe 2 minutes at most. So I believe the current draw is between 36 and 72 A. I haven’t seen any buck convertor that will handle this kind of current.
Is there a cheap/easy way for me to step down 18 V to 12 V at this kind of current draw?
I know I can buy a holder for the battery, so ideally I would like to include all the components on the mower with the holder, so it can be used exactly as the original battery was. I.e. the components should also be able to withstand the harsh vibration etc. of being hot-glued/epoxied to a petrol mower.
EDIT: I never realised this would be such a challenge for this forum, will it help if I emphasise that the current draw will be for very short time periods so I wouldn't expect heat dissipation to be a factor.
Also, it doesn't have to be very efficient - if it wastes 50% of the energy in doing the conversion, this is not really an issue.

”2 Ah battery will turn the engine for about 1 minute” That’s a 60 C battery. We’re talking RC helicopter battery territory, if even that. For a practical battery, you’ll need one with higher capacity to support that high current. Have you looked at buying a battery which can support your load without any DC-DC conversion?

@winny The guy in the video manages to turn it quite happily with an 18v drill battery, so I have no doubt that it can be done. The main point is that I have 3 18v drill batteries already sitting around that are always charged and waiting to be used, so the battery costs me nothing at all if I can step down to 12v, Can you explain what you mean by a "60 C battery" please?

See here: https://www.power-sonic.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/What-is-a-battery-C-rating.pdf

@Lefty "I have 3 18v drill batteries already sitting around" This smacks of the sunk cost fallacy  -- the tendency to continue with an endeavor we've invested money, effort, or time into — even if the current costs outweigh the benefits.

Regarding the edit -- the topics here are more towards engineering/design than piece-together solutions, or repair/maintenance topics.  There isn't much engineering content in this question -- you aren't asking how to design the converter for example -- and a better engineered (read: more broadly considered) solution might include the trivial solution (just wire it together, motors aren't picky about voltage), and alternatives you might be currently overlooking (if it looks like a drill and quacks like a drill... maybe a drill speed control would work?).

Stacks are also a strict question-answer format; if you end up having ongoing issues with realizing the solution, you may find it inconvenient (or even frustrating) to resolve that through comments, or asking further questions, rather than amending a build thread.  For these reasons, you might be better served at the DIY stack, or a forum like EEVblog.

You can usually replace the individual cells of a battery with new ones of the same chemistry and size. What are the ones it has at the moment?

@DDuck That doesn't really apply here - the 2 alternatives are 1) spend a small amount of money doing what I'm asking help with here, or. 2) Spend £400 on a replacement mower. I really do already own 3 batteries that can be used for this project if anyone has a way of doing it. I thought it was going to be something that would be easily answered by someone with expertise, but I am beginning to think that maybe I am asking the impossible.

@Lefty The easy and low-cost solution is to replace the cells in the battery with new ones, which are readily available. The cells in the drill batteries may not be suitable, but without you letting us know what the cells in the lawnmower battery are, we can't help.

@AndrewMorton This is an alternative that I might investigate now that I know it's not possible to do what I'm asking. I haven't taken the battery pack apart yet, but I assume that 10.8v is 9 * 1.2v. The pack is around the size of 9 AAA cells - certainly not big enough for 9 * AA's. This was not my preferred solution, simply because owning 3 of the drill batteries means that I always have at least 2 with a full charge, whereas, the single battery that came with the mower is often flat when I try to start it, and I have to leave it to charge for 30 minutes before I can mow the lawn.

I probably should replied in the comments, but there is not enough character space. You asked if there is a cheap/easy way for you to step down a high current  DC to DC converter. The word "high current" means expensive, and without good electronic design and fabrication skills, it will be difficult, if not impossible, for you. The easiest method is a linear 3-pin regulator with three 2N3055 transistor pass elements and a Zener diode. The most complicated method is a Buck converter. Good luck building either one.
So, now I will take off my engineering hat and put on my southern KISS engineering hat. One of my hobbies is flying electric RC aircraft; I am a 3D plane pilot, turning beautiful, expensive balsa wood planes into toothpicks. I would take one of my 3S (11.1 volts), 2200 mah 50C Lipo batteries, cut the connector off, and replace it with one that will mate with the lawn mower battery connector. If it were me, I would buy a new electric lawn mower. Another option is to look at the idiot's bibble (You Tube) for a solution.

Edit: Lefty, I watched the video and have a better idea of what the guy was doing. I looked at what you called a buck converter and instantly knew what they were. You see many on golf carts and trucks with 24-volt battery systems to power the 12-volt toys like a radio/stereo. You also see a lot of them in the Marine and RV markets. Your drill motor battery Is not a stiff enough source to worry about burning up the converter or lawn mower starter. You can find the converters at truck supplies, golf cart suppliers, and, of course, on Amazon for $20 to $30,
Your other option is to take the shrowd off the mower like the man did in the video and use your drill to start it. Good luck.

You have really just confirmed my theory - that this is not something that has an easy or cheap solution that I can buy off the shelf. I certainly am not going to be making any custom circuits for it, not buying extra battery packs. An off-the-shelf buck convertor was, in practice, actually good enough to do the job in the Youtube video I mentioned - but I believe he was putting far more power through it than he realised.
